# Dynamic usage of axios.all

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-router

I would like to re-use the same Vue-component for editing and creating new users.

As I am working with `vue-router` I added a `beforeRouteEnter`, which fetches data via API. Depending on if there's an `ID` set in the URL, I am fetching the existing user (`edit`) or not.

This is how I do it:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, _from, next) {
        if (to.params.id) {
            axios
            .all ([
                axios.get ('/api/user/' + to.params.id),
                axios.get ('/api/states/users')
            ]).then (axios.spread ((userRes, statesRes) => {
                    next ((vm) => {
                        vm.user = userRes.data.data;
                        vm.states = statesRes.data.data;
                        vm.create = false;
                    });
                })
            );
        }
        else {
            axios
            .all ([
                axios.get ('/api/states/users')
            ]).then (axios.spread ((statesRes) => {
                    next ((vm) => {
                        vm.states = statesRes.data.data;
                    });
                })
            );
        }
    },
```

But as you can see: This is not a very nice to handle this. I was thinking about adding the URL to an array and push `'/api/user/' + to.params.id)` to that array, if `to.params.id` is not empty.

But I am not sure, whether this is the best way to do this, because I'd need to handle the `axios.spread` part somehow (maybe using array keys, ...).

So my question is: How can I optimize my code for performance and a better readable code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply build the promise array before using `axios.all`. Since you're using ES6 syntax you can also omit the use of `axios.spread` in favor of array destructuring.

Here's what that would look like:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, _from, next) {
    const promises = [
        axios.get('/api/states/users')
    ];

    if (to.params.id) {
        promises.push(axios.get(`/api/user/${to.params.id}`));
    }

    axios.all(promises)
        .then(([statesRes, userRes]) => {
            next((vm) => {
                vm.states = statesRes.data.data;
                if (userRes) {
                    vm.user = userRes.data.data;
                    vm.create = false;
                }
            });
        });
}
```